# Lucene's AtomicReader.termPositionsEnum(Term) not returning offSets

Tags: solr, lucene

UPDATED: Added examples

We have an API on top of Lucene 4.6 that I'm trying to adapt to running under Solr 4.6. The problem is the way we're reading a term's character offsets from the index work as expected when the index is created by Lucene, but always return -1 when the index is created by Solr. In the latter case I can see the character offsets via Luke, and I can even get them from Solr when I access the /tvrh search handler, which uses the TermVectorComponent class.

This is roughly how I'm reading a character offset in my Lucene code:

```
public void showOffsets(Directory dir, Term term) {
  IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(dir);
  IndexReaderContext topContext = indexReader.getContext();

  for (AtomicReaderContext context : topContext.leaves()) {
    AtomicReader reader = context.reader();
    termMatches(term, reader);
  }
}

private void termMatches(Term term, AtomicReader reader) throws IOException {
  DocsAndPositionsEnum postings = reader.termPositionsEnum(term);
  if (postings != null) {
    while (postings.nextDoc() != DocsAndPositionsEnum.NO_MORE_DOCS) {
      for (int i = 0; i < postings.freq(); i++) {
        System.out.println(
          "term:" + term.toString() +
          " tokpos:" + postings.nextPosition() +
          " start:" + postings.startOffset() +
          " end:" + postings.endOffset());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that I want the values for a single term. When run against an index created by Solr, the above calls to startOffset() and endOffset() return -1, although the call to nextPosition() works OK. Solr's TermVectorComponent prints the correct offsets like this (paraphrased):

```
IndexReader reader = searcher.getIndexReader();
final Terms vector = reader.getTermVector(docId, field);
TermsEnum termsEnum = vector.iterator(termsEnum);

final int freq = (int) termsEnum.totalTermFreq();
DocsAndPositionsEnum dpEnum = null;
while((text = termsEnum.next()) != null) {
  String term = text.utf8ToString();
  dpEnum = termsEnum.docsAndPositions(null, dpEnum);
  dpEnum.nextDoc();

  for (int i = 0; i < freq; i++) {
    final int pos = dpEnum.nextPosition();

    System.out.println("start:" + dpEnum.startOffset());
    System.out.println("end:" + dpEnum.endOffset());
  }
}
```

but in this case it is getting the offsets per doc ID, rather than a single term.

Could anyone tell me:

1. Why I'm not able to get the offsets using my first example, and/or
2. A better way to get the offsets for a given term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robert Muir on the Solr email list pointed out that I was confused between the indexing options in Solr. I didn't need term vectors. Instead, I needed to add `storeOffsetsWithPositions="true"` to my field definition in the schema. After doing so and reindexing, I now get offsets as expected.